# Elasticsearch range query not working as expected

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to fetch data by applying range on date type field("timeA" in this case).

My query is:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "name": "A"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "timeA": {
              "lte": 9999
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I don't have any data less then 1558891800000 in timeA filed.

SO the expected output has to be:

```
  "took": 0,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}
```

But the actual output I'm getting is:

```
{
  "took": 0,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1.287682,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "checktimestamp",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "AWr4sdJv_fFf5JZrQhXl",
        "_score": 1.287682,
        "_source": {
          "name": "A",
          "timeA": 1558899000000,
          "timeLocal": "27-1AM"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The Type of timeA field is date.
My elasticsearch version is 5.6.10 and Kibana version is  5.6.10.

Please suggest what is the problem here and how can I resolve it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Elastic parses the 4 digits as a year meaning it matches documents with a year less or equal to 9999, which i'm assuming is all your data.

To avoid this your need to define in your mapping a strict [format](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html) for your date field, this will now allow a "yyyy" format to sneak in.
or alternatively don't use numbers with less than 5 digits in those queries.

Comment: Thanks Tom, now I got why it was not returning expected output.